# highlight-indent-guides-mode

Tags: init-file, indentation

I'm trying to activate highlight-indent-guides-mode by default but it is not working. 
If i do <kbd>M-x</kbd> `highlight-indent-guides-mode` it works fine but adding `(highlight-indent-guides-mode 1)` to my `.emacs` file does not activates the mode. Any suggestions?

Here is the part of my `.emacs` file:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/manualinstalled/")
(load "guides")
(highlight-indent-guides-mode 1)
```

Comment: I'm assuming that `highlight-indent-guides-mode` is a minor mode. The package might also provide a global version of it, and if it doesn't,  you'll probably want to enable it in a hook.

Answer (score 1):

`highlight-indent-guides-mode` is buffer-local, not global.  The comments at the beginning of the library https://github.com/DarthFennec/highlight-indent-guides/blob/master/highlight-indent-guides.el state in relevant part:

```
;; ... To enable it automatically in
;; most programming modes, use the following:
;;
;;   (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'highlight-indent-guides-mode)
```

In your `.emacs` file, remove `(highlight-indent-guides-mode 1)` and replace it with:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'highlight-indent-guides-mode)
```

The original poster has apparently broken from tradition in that Emacs users normally keep the existing name of the file `highlight-indent-guides.el` the same, and do not alter the `provide` statement at the bottom of the file.  To the extent the original file name and `provide` statement remain unchanged, we would change `(load "guides")` to `(require 'highlight-indent-guides)`.

For more information regarding this library, have a look at the `READE.md` file of the repository:

https://github.com/DarthFennec/highlight-indent-guides